# Problem: Linking to specific CMS page from external page

Tags: login, redirects, admin, admin.php

I've created an external "admin" page, but added a "Return to CMS" link .When this is clicked it redirects back to the EE admin page BUT it's logged me out and the URL is something like:

http://website.com/admin.php?S=0&D=cp&C=login&return=Qz1hZGRvbnNfbW9kdWxlcyZhbXA7TT1zaG93X21vZHVsZV9jcCZhbXA7bW9kdWxlPWxvd192YXJpYWJsZXM=

Is it possible to link back to the CMS, but still be logged in? Because it seems to be logging me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the [Control Panel Session Type](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/security_settings.html#control-panel-session-type) to **Cookie only**.

Comment: Amazing! Did the trick!